# Test works when debugging using VS, throws System.IO.IOException when using mstest.exe

Tags: testing, visual-studio-2015, automated-tests, mstest, regression-testing

I noticed a strange behaviour during automated execution of regression tests. They fail when I execute them with `mstest.exe /test:XYZ /...` but they work fine when I debug them in Visual Studio (2015 Enterprise).
Reason:

```
Test method XYZ threw exception: 
System.IO.IOException:  not found as file or resource.
```

The test creates some files and folders and I try to read a newly created file. As I just pointed out: It works fine if I use Visual Studio to run the test - when using mstest.exe it doesn't work.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

`MsTest.exe` is left around for backwards compatibility. You should be using `vstest.console.exe`.  This usually corrects most issues that exist when things work in the IDE, but not from the CLI.